# При использовании meta данных (<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">) увеличивается экран

Tags: html, css, meta, adaptive

Всё выглядит вот так. Что сделать чтобы всё смотрелось нормально? Когда его убираю то всё +- нормально[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

это свойство полностью убирать нельзя, сайт априори станет не адаптивным,если не хотите чтобы пользователь мог увеличить изображение то можно так:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

но для юзабилити не рекомендуют это делать, залучше чтобы была возможность зумить, например:

```
maximum-scale=5
```